# "Sus" Versus "Sous"

Tags: prépositions

In the song, "C'est si bon," it talks about a couple walking "bras dessus, bras dessous."

I understand "dessous" to be "under." As in "Sous le ciel de Paris."

But how does "dessus" become "over?" Would "sus" be short for "sur" (on) in this context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in this context, *sus* is similar to *sur*. The word *sus* still exists and [originally meant *en haut* (up)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/sus). (go to third tab `SUS, adv.`).

Originally, [the forms *desur*, *desor* et *desus* coexisted until *desus* took off and ultimately became *dessus*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/dessus). I assume it was easier to say. Note however that *sur* took precedence over *sus* an *sor*, so that *sus*, even if it still exists, has lost its meaning as a preposition.

---

Answer (score 5):

The word “*sus*” is not often used with the meaning of “*dessus*” anymore. The only occurrences you would probably find nowadays would appear in “*sus-cité*”, which means “cited above”, “*cité plus haut*”, “*cité au-dessus*”. (Not to be confused with “*[sucité](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/susciter)*”).

Answer (score 4):

[Sus](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sus) (see the etymology section) has been used with the meaning of "sur", but it is no more in common usage excepted in some expressions (*courir sus à l'ennemi*, *en sus*) and even these are perceived as old fashioned (at least by me).